Why &i doesn't change?
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  for(int i = 0; i<4; i++){
    printf("i: %d\n", i);
    printf("&i: %p\n", &i);
  }

  return 0;
}

I want to know why &i is still the same value...
Because I thought that it  has to change in every step of the loop.

Why can't it re-use the same address?

I don't understand why you think it would change. It is one variable that has a lifetime through the last iteration of the loop. It is equivalent to { int i; for( i = 0; i<4; i++){ . . . } }

I don't know...

What was your thought process?

I thought that, as i change from 0 to 4, the adresses has to change also...

&i is the pointer to/address of the variable, it is not changed during the loop. The value of variable i changes.

There is only ONE i, so only ONE address. The value stored at that address changes with each iteration, but the address itself does not.

See C Standard - 6.8.5.3 The for statement and specifically "clause-1".

"I thought that, as i change from 0 to 4, the adresses has to change also... " - So, do you think that a variable's address changes each time a value is assigned to it?  That's not how C variables work.  The variable's address stays the same.

(There are some languages where a variable's memory address can change during its lifetime.  For example, languages with garbage collectors.  But C is not such a language.)

The contents of your mailbox might change as the postman takes stuff in and out of it. The location (address) of your mailbox stays the same regardless of what's in it.

If you really want to blow your mind, add a second for loop. Its variable address will probably be the same as in the first loop, because it reuses the memory.

No, please no @Barmar because, I am reading all stuff about pointers and I am more confuse than before, jajaja.

When you declare a variable you ask for memory.
int i;

That will create a location, with an address. You can access the address by using &.
When you assign a value to i, the address does not change the value at the address does.
i = 0;

i has a value of 0, but the address hasn't changed.
i = 1;

Same thing, you're putting the value at the address that i is referring to.
In your example. for(int i = 0; i<4; i++) The i is being declared one time so the address will not change for the life of the for loop.
In this example j will have it's own address. It can change on each iteration, though it probably won't because memory addresses are re-used.
for(int i = 0; i<4; i++){
    int j = i;
    printf("%d ... &i %p &j %p\n", j, &i, &j)
}


The integer i is allocated memory on the stack when the loop starts, and while the value of the integer changes with each iteration of the loop, the address of i remains the same throughout the loop.
&i points to the address at which i is located. The address of the variable does not change when you change it's value.

Based on this @matt's guess:

In this example j will have it's own address. It can change on each iteration, though it probably won't because memory addresses are re-used.

for (int i = 0; i<4; i++) {
    int j = i;
    printf("%d ... &i %p &j %p\n", j, &i, &j);
}

I decided to give a detailed answer about memory allocation for local variables.
In short, there is such a thing as the scope (of variables). Such scopes are enclosed in curly brackets {}. In the C language, these include: functions fn(...) {}, blocks if(...) {} else {}, for(...) {}, while(...) {}, do {} while(...), just curly braces {}. Some scopes may contain other scopes. Variables declared in external scopes are visible in nested scopes. But variables declared in sibling scopes do not see each other. This is due to the fact that after optimization by the compiler, they can occupy the same addresses. Try compiling this code with -O3 (gcc) / -Ox (msvc) optimization key:
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    if (i % 2) {
        int j = i;
        printf("j: %d,  &i: %p,  &j: %p\n", j, &i, &j);
    }
    else {
        int k = i;
        printf("k: %d,  &i: %p,  &k: %p\n", k, &i, &k);
    }
}

Most likely the result will be like this:
k: 0,  &i: 000000286131F960,  &k: 000000286131F964
j: 1,  &i: 000000286131F960,  &j: 000000286131F964
k: 2,  &i: 000000286131F960,  &k: 000000286131F964
j: 3,  &i: 000000286131F960,  &j: 000000286131F964

That is, variable j from one scope and variable k from another scope occupy the same address, although they are named differently. (The addresses will most likely be different without optimization.)

Now add the variable l1 before the variable k and the variable l2 after the variable k to the second scope. And pass these variables as parameters to printf function so that the compiler doesn't ignore them. This trick will force almost any compiler to shift the variable k to a different address:
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    if (i % 2) {
        int j = i;
        printf("i: %d,  &i: %p,  &j: %p\n", j, &i, &j);
    }
    else {
        int l1 = i;
        int k = i;
        int l2 = i;
        printf("k: %d,  &i: %p,  &k: %p\n", k, &i, &k, &l1, &l2);
    }
}

Most likely the result will be like this:
k: 0,  &i: 000000EE1DFBFB60,  &k: 000000EE1DFBFB6C
i: 1,  &i: 000000EE1DFBFB60,  &j: 000000EE1DFBFB64
k: 2,  &i: 000000EE1DFBFB60,  &k: 000000EE1DFBFB6C
i: 3,  &i: 000000EE1DFBFB60,  &j: 000000EE1DFBFB64

Now the variables j and k have different addresses, but this address doesn't change from iteration to iteration. Because this address (more precisely, the offset in the stack) is assigned during compilation, when the compiler looks through all possible branches of the code. The addresses (offset in the stack) will be constant even in conditional if-else, while, do-while scopes, not to mention for scopes.

I'm not sure what I guessed about, but your first example that uses a j and a k actually doesn't require scope. You can declare j and k at the same level inside the loop instead of inside the even check blocks and it will re-use the address...maybe. It probably depends on the compiler and platform etc.

I didn't assign them right away. I said, int j, k and then within the odd-even blocks I would assign either j or k.

Yes, you're right. Only gcc compiler has done this. But that's enough: https://godbolt.org/z/MM9bqceWE

If i will build your program,then i will can see out:
i: 0
&i: 0x7fffffffd9d4
i: 1
&i: 0x7fffffffd9d4
i: 2
&i: 0x7fffffffd9d4
i: 3
&i: 0x7fffffffd9d4

Your value is change because you used "i++" but compiler automatice allow memory for variable after start a program on address 0x7fffffffd9d4 and change address is imposible!
Follow code may be can help you for understand:
  int *i;
  i=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
  *i=0;
  printf("i: %d\n", *i);
  printf("&i: %p\n", &i);
  printf("&i: %p\n", i);
  *i+=1;
  printf("i: %d\n", *i);
  printf("&i: %p\n", &i);
  printf("&i: %p\n", i);
  i++;
  printf("i: %d\n", *i);
  printf("&i: %p\n", &i);
  printf("&i: %p\n", i);
  for (*i=0;*i<4;*i++)
  {
      printf("i: %d\n", *i);
      printf("&i: %p\n", &i);
      printf("&i: %p\n", i);
  }
  free(i);
  return 0;

and out:
&i: 0x7fffffffd9d0
&i: 0x55555556b2b0
i: 1
&i: 0x7fffffffd9d0
&i: 0x55555556b2b0
i: 0
&i: 0x7fffffffd9d0
&i: 0x55555556b2b4
i: 0
&i: 0x7fffffffd9d0
&i: 0x55555556b2b4
i: 0
&i: 0x7fffffffd9d0
&i: 0x55555556b2b8
i: 0
&i: 0x7fffffffd9d0
&i: 0x55555556b2bc
i: 0
&i: 0x7fffffffd9d0
&i: 0x55555556b2c0
i: 0
&i: 0x7fffffffd9d0
&i: 0x55555556b2c4


In "for" i can see output = 0, but it is a random values in my memory.
